# Rails - Should I use boolean fields or relational table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

User model has three keys: `is_master`, `is_standard`, `is_guest` because I originally wanted to use [activerecord](https://rubygems.org/gems/activerecord)'s boolean methods like `is_master`? or `is_power`?.

However, if it would be better to create a UserType relationship and create my own methods like this:

```
def master?
   return true if self.user_type = 1
end
```

Comment: Pardon me, I could not help it but code you have written needs refactoring. >>def master? >>>> 1 == self.user_type >> end is same as what you have written, but only efficient. (Doh! There is no way to format code inside comments in SO. '>'s in the code mean indentation.)

Comment: Just a FYI: Do self.user_type == 1. That returns a boolean, so that you don't have to return a boolean manualy via an if test.

Answer (score 2):

If the master/standard/guest relationship is mutually exclusive (that is, you can only ever be one of them) then a field that stores the type (in a human-readable form, please -- no opaque numbers) is better.  You can always reimplement `is_foo?` trivially.

On the other hand, if you could have an account that be more than one of master/standard/guest/whatever at once, then stick with the separate boolean fields.

Answer (score 1):

As a DBA I always hate when people are using columns as flags, it would be a lot of extra columns. 
If it is all the same type (like account type), I would do as the first anwer suggests (including using text, not numbers).

If you on the other hand needs it for separate flags or multiple types (but having a restricted number) I would actually go for a binary calculation.

That is, have one columns in the table representing all the flags and then assign each flag a number.

ex.

```
FLAGS = {:master => 1, :standard => 2, :guest => 4, :power => 8, 
         :another_flag => 32, :yet_another_flag => 64}

def is_master?
    self.flags & FLAGS[:master]
end

def is_standard?
    self.flags & FLAGS[:standard]
end
```

It requires a bit more work when setting the values, but doesn't clutter up the table with a lot of columns used only for flags.

Comment: Since you are using Rails I assume you might be using MySQL. To my knowledge MySQL does not support bitmap indexes. Thus if you want to find all users with a given flag then you might do a query like SELECT * FROM users WHERE (flags&1 = 1) which will not use an index and do a full table scan.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at how the restful authentication plugin does it (which includes user roles) they use a join table.

I think a join is much more readable.Using a join allows you to be more flexible with your role-system.

If you require that a user can only have a single role I would put that logic in your model.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start with the simplest thing that solves your current need. Refactor and add complexity from there as needed. Sounds like a set of boolean columns is just what you need.